# android:imeOptions="actionNext" is not working when android:inputType="textCapWords"

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

`actionNext` is not working when

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

but its working in

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Can some one help to fix this

Below you can see my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_firstNameLay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/TextLabel1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.orbiosolutions.yabeee.CustomClasses.CustomEditText
                    android:id="@+id/profile_firstNameTxt"
                    android:textColor="@color/login_txt_color"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/login_med_txt_size"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:hint="@string/first_name" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: have u add singleline =true in xml

Answer (score 1):

add singleLine = true

or

maxLines = 1

in your .xml file